# Is there a tool that will explain what each symbol in a Scala program means and how it is parsed?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, tooltip

I'm trying to learn Scala and am confused by the terse syntax and difficult-to-search operators, methods, and implicit. Other terse languages have tools like https://regexr.com/ or  Take the following program:

```
object SampleMain {

  val sample: Parser[Sample] =
    ^(
      strOption(long("hello"), metavar("TARGET"), help("Target for the greeting")),
      switch(long("quiet"), help("Whether to be quiet"))
    )(Sample.apply)

  def greet(s: Sample): Unit = s match {
    case Sample(h, false) => println("Hello, " ++ h)
    case _ =>
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val opts = info(sample <*> helper,
      progDesc("Print a greeting for TARGET"),
      header("hello - a test for scala-optparse-applicative"))
    greet(execParser(args, "SampleMain", opts))
  }

}
```

I'd to be able to hover over `^`, `<*>`, or other symbols and have the tool show me the documentation for them.

Comment: Well, any good editor will show you the documentation since all those are just plain methods, nothing too magic. - Also, you should probably search for those symbols in the **Scaladoc** for whatever library you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Those are not standard Scala symbols, so you need to look at the documentation for the library that provides them. It will be `import`ed somewhere at the top of the file.

IntelliJ IDEA will give you information if you hover over the symbol with ALT pressed, and take you to the library if you ALT click on it. There should be some basic documentation in the code.

Comment: For instance somewhere in a wildcard import (e.g. a `package object`) there's a method that probably looks like `def ^[T](o1: SomeSuperType, o2: SomeSuperType)(f: (SomeSuperType, SomeSuperType) => T): Parser[Sample]`.  Scala's syntax, strictly speaking, is really small (Dotty is, syntactically, simpler than Python or Golang; Scala 2 isn't that much more complex).